# Flutter QuerySnapshot: The getter 'docs' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting the error "NoSuchMethodeError: The getter 'docs' was called on null." with the following code:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;

  initiateSearch() {
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
      querySnapshot = val;
    });
  }

  Widget searchList() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: querySnapshot.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SearchTile(
            userName: querySnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"],
            userEmail: querySnapshot.docs[index].data()["email"],
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

If someone has an answer why `querySnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"]` is not working, and I'm getting this error and how to fix it please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rebuild the UI in sync with the state changes, we should use state management, easiest being the `setState()` function of a `StatefulWidget`:

```
QuerySnapshot _querySnapshot;

initiateSearch() {
  databaseMethods
      .getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text)
      .then((val) {
          setState(() {
             _querySnapshot = val;
          });
  });
}
```

And handle the situation when the `_querySnapshot` is still null:

```
 Widget searchList() {
    if (_querySnapshot == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _querySnapshot.data.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SearchTile(
            userName: _querySnapshot.data.docs[index]["name"],
            userEmail: _querySnapshot.data.docs[index]["email"],
          );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: At `querySnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"]` is still the error "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'."

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This was another issue, I've edited the answer to address that as well, I hope this helps! :)